# How Notifications Mechanism Works

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, comet, ape

I am working on an application using MongoDB and PHP, wherein the user receives notification updates for various events(something like FB Notifications).
I have read something about APE, node.js, and Comet Server Push Technology. But being new to this, I am not sure how to proceed with this w.r.t my application. Which will be better option?

Comment: You could use AJAX based techniques or look out for WebSockets

Comment: As per what think, Websockets are not supported by all browsers. And we don't want the client to continuously contact server. Instead the server shud contact client in case of notifications.

Comment: But that's not the way how it works. There is always an open connection needed, even when it's called push notification. As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) says: 'A client might "subscribe" to various information "channels". Whenever new content is available on one of those channels, the server would push that information out to the user.' But you are right it's not working on all browsers, so you should consider using AJAX. Try out jQuery, it's a breeze to get work done with it.

Answer (score 0):

you can made this mechanism by yourself using core concept 
first make a extra column in your database named flag or anything by default set its value to 0 if any new record will insert in this table than this record flag value will 0 then at login time check all and fetch records having the value of flag column is 0 
after clicking open that data in any pace or page and set the flag value to 1